# Story where protagonist finds a gemstone that powers a machine

Tags: story-identification

I read a book series in high school and I can't remember much about it but I would like to find it. The main character was female, there was a war happening and the main character finds a gemstone that is perfect, it is used to power war machines.  She discovers that it holds the power to give the machine flight. I'm fairly sure the stone was purple, the enemy is described as insect like but are humanoid.

Comment: You say you read this in high school, when was that? Can you remember anymore details? If you remember anything, you can [edit] it into your question.

Comment: As TLC says, take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) which has proven helpful dozens of time, and if you remember anything, you can always just [edit] it in.